# Getting a reference to the child component's element in the parent component

Tags: angular, components

I want to access the child component's element (`#sidenav`) in parent component (`toggleSidebar()`). I tried to apply this solution without success: [angular 2 / typescript:
 get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template)

**My Child Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  template: `
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav">
  Sidenav
  </md-sidenav>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**My Parent Component:**

```
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  <app-toolbar (toggleSidebar)="toggleSidebar()"></app-toolbar>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('sidenav') sidebar: SidebarComponent;

  constructor() { }

  toggleSidebar() {
    this.sidebar.toggle();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is sidenav in the parent component?

Comment: Have you tried it `<app-sidebar #sidenav></app-sidebar>`?

Comment: @yurzui yes but it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work because you're trying to call method on `md-sidenav`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update for Angular 8:**

```
@ViewChild(SidebarComponent, {static: false}) sidebar: SidebarComponent;
```

For more info check: https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration

---

You should get the child component from parent with

```
@ViewChild(SidebarComponent) sidebar: SidebarComponent;
```

so remove the `sidenav`

and add it to the child component to get hold of that element.

```
@ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav;
```

finally call your child components `sidenav` field from parent to do whatever you want.

`this.sidebar.sidenav// <-- selects child components element`

**parent**:

```
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  <app-toolbar (toggleSidebar)="toggleSidebar()"></app-toolbar>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild(SidebarComponent) sidebar: SidebarComponent;

  constructor() { }

  toggleSidebar() {
    this.sidebar.sidenav.toggle();
  }
}
```

**child:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  template: `
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav">
  Sidenav
  </md-sidenav>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: @Gabriel glad I could help :-)

Comment: Seems this should also work `<app-sidebar #sidebar></app-sidebar><app-toolbar (toggleSidebar)="sidebar.sidenav.toggle()"></app-toolbar>`